# SELECT из MySQL ( JOIN )

Tags: mysql

Выборка из 2-х таблиц.

```
ТАБЛИЦА 1
userID          NAME
1               ВАСЯ
2               ПЕТЯ
ТАБЛИЦА 2 ( user_contacts )
userID          type          КАКАЯ
1               email         email@mail.ru
2               phone         +2222222
```

Нужно составить запрос к БД и получить данные в виде.

```
Array (
    0=>array (
        Id=>1
        Name=> Имя 1
        user_contacts=>array(
    0=>array(
        Type=>email
        Value=>+222222222
                 ) 
            …
              )
          ) 
)
```

Я пробывал

```
SELECT `user`.* 
FROM `user` 
LEFT JOIN `user_contact` 
  ON `user_contact`.`userID` = `user`.`userID`
```

Но значения повторяются столько раз, сколько записей во 2 таблице
а нужно что бы было внутри еще 1 array

```
Array (
    0 => array (
        Id => 1
        Name => Имя 1
                type => email
                value => +22222222
          ) 
          ...
)
```

Comment: Это невозможно в реляционных базах данных. Результат выборки- всегда набор строк, а не древовидная структура.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за ответ. Но можно как то это получить, не теряя много производительности ? 
Т.к Производительность это очень важно в моем случаи.
И делать SELECT для каждой записи не очень.

Или хотя бы выбрать 1 такую запись, это возможно ? 
LIMIT 1 ( на 2 таблицу )